# Create Highchart (Column chart) and read data from external json file

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I have to create a column chart in my project using Highchart.I have `JSON` file that contain some data look like:

```
{
    "meta": [
        "rectime",
        "strid",
        "ambt",
        "stri",
        "b1",
        "b2",
        "b3",
        "b4"
    ],
    "data": [
        [
            1377597739,
            1,
            0,
            77,
            816,
            13791,
            13794,
            13945
        ],
        [
            1377597739,
            2,
            0,
            0,
            816,
            13744,
            13725,
            13898
        ]
    ]
}
```

May anyone can suggest me about what should I do.

ThanKs all helping

Comment: You need something like this: `var options = { xAxis: { categories: json.meta }, series: [{ data: json.data[0] }, { data: json.data[1] }]};` And then use that options when creating chart.

Comment: My project is created column to show the info. of the battery. In 1 battery will have many data so can I use this example http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic to be a guideline @Pawel Fus

Comment: Could you be more clear..? What do you expect me to do with that information?

Comment: I have a JSON file that contain the data of batteries as Voltage, Current, Lifetime , etc. There are many batteries so I want to create Highchart as Column Chart with 1 column show all data of 1 battery. 

I want to know that how to create column chart with use data from external JSON file that I have. @PawełFus

Comment: So you have to chnage format for Highcharts. You need to loop through all data and push that into separate arrays, for example: `series: [{ data: [1377597739, 1377597739] }, { data: [1, 2] } ... {data: [13945,13898] }]` And rememver to set `stacking: 'normal'` In plotOptions.

Answer (score 0):

after you recieve the response (I mean the JSON) in success call back pass the response.data to a routine which will parse this JSON data as accepted by Highcharts.

```
series:[{
name: 'series 1'
data: [1,2,4,5,6,74]
},{
name: 'series 2'
data: [1,2,4,5,6,74]
},{
name: 'series 3'
data: [1,2,4,5,6,74]
}]
```

you can exclude name if you don't want to give a specific name to every series. although highcharts generates unique name for every series.

to get the column chart set the type to column.

```
chart:{
type: 'column'
}
```